# Show that $ \sum_k \binom{r}{k} \binom{s+k}{n} (-1)^k = (-1)^r \binom{s}{n-r} $

Tags: combinatorics

I can't resolve this exercise and I need tips.

Let be $n$ integer, $s$ real and $r \geq 0$ integer. Show that

$$ \sum_k \binom{r}{k} \binom{s+k}{n} (-1)^k = (-1)^r \binom{s}{n-r} $$

Comment: Which techniques are you familiar with? I think I see an nice application of generating functions, but inclusion-exclusion could work as well.

Comment: Check this [technique](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/921917/how-to-solve-sum-m-0k-1mc-k-1mc-n-km/922852#922852).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Vandermonde's Identity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde%27s_identity) says
$$
\binom{s+k}{n}=\sum_{j=0}^n\binom{s}{n-j}\binom{k}{j}\tag{1}
$$
Thus,
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=0}^r(-1)^k\binom{r}{k}\binom{s+k}{n}
&=\sum_{k=0}^r(-1)^k\binom{r}{k}\sum_{j=0}^n\binom{s}{n-j}\binom{k}{j}\tag{2}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^r\sum_{j=0}^n(-1)^k\binom{r}{k}\binom{k}{j}\binom{s}{n-j}\tag{3}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^r\sum_{j=0}^n(-1)^k\binom{r}{j}\binom{r-j}{k-j}\binom{s}{n-j}\tag{4}\\
&=(-1)^r\binom{s}{n-r}\tag{5}
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$(2)$: apply $(1)$
$(3)$: rearrange terms
$(4)$: $\binom{r}{k\vphantom{j}}\binom{k}{j}=\binom{r}{j}\binom{r-j}{k-j}$ (just write out the coefficients in terms of factorials)
$(5)$: $\sum\limits_{k=0}^r(-1)^k\binom{r-j}{k-j}=\sum\limits_{k=0}^{r-j}(-1)^{k+j}\binom{r-j}{k}=(-1)^j(1-1)^{r-j}=(-1)^j[j=r]$

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you did on $(5)$?

Comment: Since $\binom{r}{j}$ is a factor of the summand, we can assume $r\ge j$. The first sum is the same as $\sum\limits_{k=j}^r(-1)^k\binom{r-j}{k-j}$ since $\binom{r-j}{k-j}=0$ for $k-j\lt0$. The next sum follows by substituting $k\mapsto k+j$. Applying the Binomial Theorem yields $(-1)^j(1-1)^{r-j}=(-1)^j[j=r]$.

Comment: Thanks for answering to a comment in an almost 10 years response, I appreciate it. And yeah, I figured it out as well this morning, I'll post it in an answer apart to complement this.

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
$\ds{\sum_{k}{r \choose k}{s + k \choose n}\pars{-1}^{k}
    = \pars{-1}^{r}{s \choose n - r}:\ {\large ?}}.\quad$
$\ds{n\ \mbox{integer}, s\ \mbox{real and}\  r\ \mbox{an integer}\ \geq 0}$.

> \begin{align}
> &\color{#66f}{\large\sum_{k}{r \choose k}{s + k \choose n}\pars{-1}^{k}}
> =\sum_{k}{r \choose k}\pars{-1}^{k}\oint_{\verts{z}\ =\ 1}{\pars{1 + z}^{s + k} \over z^{n + 1}}
> \,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}
> \\[3mm]&=\oint_{\verts{z}\ =\ 1}{\pars{1 + z}^{s} \over z^{n + 1}}
> \sum_{k}{r \choose k}\pars{-1 - z}^{k}\,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}
> =\oint_{\verts{z}\ =\ 1}{\pars{1 + z}^{s} \over z^{n + 1}}
> \bracks{1 + \pars{-1 - z}}^{r}\,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}
> \\[3mm]&=\pars{-1}^{r}\oint_{\verts{z}\ =\ 1}{\pars{1 + z}^{s} \over z^{n - r + 1}}
> \,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}
> =\color{#66f}{\large\pars{-1}^{r}{s \choose n - r}}
> \end{align}

Answer (score 0):

I'm just posting this to add what I did starting from $(4)$ in robjohn answer.

$$
\sum_{k=0}^r(-1)^k\binom{r}{k}\binom{s+k}{n}=\sum_{k=0}^r\sum_{j=0}^n(-1)^k\binom{r}{j}\binom{r-j}{k-j}\binom{s}{n-j}
$$
In order to keep the inner sum consistent, we have to restrict the values of $j$ to $j=0,1,2,\cdots,r$ so this way the $\binom{r}{j}$ is always non zero, then:

$$
\sum_{k=0}^r(-1)^k\binom{r}{k}\binom{s+k}{n}=\sum_{k=0}^r\sum_{j=0}^r(-1)^k\binom{r}{j}\binom{r-j}{k-j}\binom{s}{n-j}
$$

Now setting $j=t$ a fixed value of $j$ on the inner sum, which can be $0,1,2,\cdots,r$, we can examine what happens to the overall sum. So we have

$$
\sum_{k=0}^r(-1)^k\binom{r}{t}\binom{r-t}{k-t}\binom{s}{n-t}=\binom{r}{t}\binom{s}{n-t}\sum_{k=0}^r(-1)^k\binom{r-t}{k-t} \tag{*}
$$

Here, at right hand side we see that the factor $\binom{r-t}{k-t}$ is non zero only if $k \geq t$, then:

$$
\sum_{k=0}^r(-1)^k\binom{r}{t}\binom{r-t}{k-t}\binom{s}{n-t}=\binom{r}{t}\binom{s}{n-t}\sum_{k=t}^r(-1)^k\binom{r-t}{k-t}
$$

Shifting index in the right hand side sum:

$$
\sum_{k=0}^r(-1)^k\binom{r}{t}\binom{r-t}{k-t}\binom{s}{n-t}=\binom{r}{t}\binom{s}{n-t}\sum_{k=0}^{r-t}(-1)^{k+t}\binom{r-t}{k}
$$
$$
=(-1)^t\binom{r}{t}\binom{s}{n-t} \sum_{k=0}^{r-t}\binom{r-t}{k}(-1)^{k}
=(-1)^t\binom{r}{t}\binom{s}{n-t}(1-1)^{r-t}
=0
$$
For all $t<r$.

But for $t=r$ , from $($*$)$ we have that:

$$
\sum_{k=0}^r(-1)^k\binom{r}{r}\binom{r-r}{k-r}\binom{s}{n-r}=\binom{s}{n-r}\sum_{k=0}^{r}(-1)^{k}\binom{0}{k-r}
$$

Where the facotr $\binom{0}{k-r}$ is non zero only when $k=r$. Therefore, the only term in $($*$)$ that remains is the one with $j=k=r$, which is:
$$
\binom{s}{n-r}(-1)^{r}\binom{0}{r-r}=\binom{s}{n-r}(-1)^{r}\binom{0}{0}=(-1)^{r}\binom{s}{n-r}
$$

Finally:

$$
\sum_{k=0}^r\sum_{j=0}^r(-1)^k\binom{r}{j}\binom{r-j}{k-j}\binom{s}{n-j}=(-1)^{r}\binom{s}{n-r}
$$